# Set CheckBox "Checked" propery in ASP repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, asprepeater

I was wondering if it's possible to set the checked propery of a checkbox, using a bool variable form the repeater's datasource?

I've tried several ways but without any success...:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
    <itemTemplate> 
       <asp:CheckBox runat="server" CssClass="checkbox"
            Checked="<%#Eval("IsDefault").ToString().ToLower()%>"
            ID="isDefaultCheckBox"/>
    </itemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
    <itemTemplate> 
       <asp:CheckBox runat="server" CssClass="checkbox" 
            Checked="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsDefault")%>" 
            ID="isDefaultCheckBox"/>
    </itemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

IsDefault is a field in a class View:

```
public bool IsDefault
```

The repeater's DataSource is List.

Comment: Have you also tried this: `Checked='<%#Eval("IsDefault") %>'`?

Comment: Yes - also doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution is handling ItemDataBound event:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt_ItemDataBound">
    <itemTemplate> 
       <asp:CheckBox runat="server" CssClass="checkbox" ID="isDefaultCheckBox"/>
    </itemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

...

```
protected void rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem ri = e.Item;
    var dataItem = ri.DataItem as YourClassOrInterface;
    var isDefaultCheckBox = ri.FindControl("isDefaultCheckBox") as CheckBox;
    isDefaultCheckBox.Checked = dataItem.IsDefault;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly sure that it should work this way:

```
Checked='<%# Bind("IsDefault") %>'
```

By the way, there's a missing `<` in your first approach:

```
Checked="%#Eval...
```

**Edit**: <sub>(since you've also edited your question and corrected it)</sub>

Now there's something else wrong, you've two consecutive quotes here:

```
Checked="<%#Eval("
```

Comment: My mistake, while copying the code. With '<%# Eval("IsDefault") %>' still doesn't work.

Comment: @looked into an old project, i've used `Bind` there for a checkbox' checked property. See my edited answer. Are you really sure that it's a boolean in the datasource?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I dont know why, but still doesn't work in your way.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but I solved this in my application using something much simpler:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkIncludePdf" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("DefaultInclude").ToString() == "True" %>' />
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the code is actually the fact that you are nesting double quotes

```
Checked="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsDefault")%>"
```

should be

```
Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsDefault")%>'
```