# ASP.NET repeater get all items and checkbox if user has right

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, repeater

I have an ASP.NET application and I would like to display all roles and add a checkbox which is checked if the user has the right.
I use an ASP repeater to get all roles but how can I check the checkbox in the same repeater to get the user's role ?
Here is my code:

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterRole" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Checked="False" />
                <asp:Label CssClass="lbl" ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RoleLabel")%>'></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAllRolesToCollection" TypeName="Business.BusinessObject.Role"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073670/set-checkbox-checked-propery-in-asp-repeater

Comment: John, this has nothing to do with [tag:asp-classic], please retag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterRole" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("role")) %>'  />
                <asp:Label CssClass="lbl" ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RoleLabel")%>'></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAllRolesToCollection" TypeName="Business.BusinessObject.Role"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

**Make sure you get 'role' field 1 or 0 from DB**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Hardik,
based on your solution, I created a similar method like this: public Dictionary GetAllRolesFromUserToDictionary() so the checkbox will bind to the boolean value
Then the ASP code is like this:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource3">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Value")%>' />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Key")%>'></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource3" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAllRolesFromCurrentUserToDictionary" TypeName="BusinessObject.RoleCollection"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```